# Evaluate stochastic integration

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

> I need to evaluate
>   $$
> \int_0^t B(\min \{{1,s}\})dB(s),
> $$
>   where $B$ is the Brownian motion.

I am starting solving this problem by using the stochastic integration. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**
Assuming $t > 1$,
$$
\int_0^t B_{\min\{1,s\}} dB_s
 = \int_0^1 B_{\min\{1,s\}} dB_s
 + \int_1^t B_{\min\{1,s\}} dB_s
$$
Now $\min\{1,s\}$ can be explicitly computed over each interval of integration. Can you now finish?

Comment: The first part would be B(s) dB(s) and second part B(1)dB(s) then evaluate the two parts, is it correct

Comment: @Gouli yes, exactly

Comment: @Gouli don't forget to accept the answer you've been given! :)